# Identify this SciFi short story from the 80's or earlier

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm going crazy trying to find a story I once read.

In it, a wealthy futuristic family live in separate rooms in a sterile pod like house. They communicate through video screens, and take different pills to experience different emotions.

The main character, the daughter of the family, leaves to find a man in the outside world she has become obsessed with. I think they speak different languages, and he already has a wife, when she finds him.

Has anyone but me ever read this?

Does anyone know the title and author?

Answer (score 5):

I found it. Not a short story but a novel: [*A Very Private Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Very_Private_Life) by Michael Frayn.

From Wikipedia's plot summary:

> The protagonist (Uncumber) begins life in a privileged home where she is estranged from her family by their reliance on drugs to regulate their emotions and social interactions. She leaves them in order to pursue a man (Noli) that she falls in love with on first sight despite a language barrier existing between them, which stops her from forming any relationships with him or his family. Noli unlike Uncumber is from the working class and she finally abandons him when he insists on using the drugs which she abhors in their love making.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that you found this! Please remember to come back and accept this answer tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, good job! I hope you don't mind that I took the liberty of editing in a little more detail about the book, so that others can see it matches the one you described in your question.